# Trying to request information from "IDEALISTA webpage" in PYTHON with "requests" and I get <Response [403]>

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, http-headers, http-status-code-403

Its a easy starting project that I'm doing, but the main body would be accesing to the information on the Webpage , so , I don't know if i'm doing something wrong

the starting code is: (to see if it works on Fotocasa Webpage)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/vivienda/valencia-capital/aire-acondicionado-trastero-ascensor-no-amueblado/161485852/d'
# url = 'https://www.idealista.com/inmueble/97795476/'

headers = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'es,es-ES;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'dnt': '1',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="106", "Microsoft Edge";v="106", "Not;A=Brand";v="99"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/106.0.1370.47'
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(r)

req = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text

# Now that the content is ready, iterate
# through the content using BeautifulSoup:
soup = BeautifulSoup(req, "html.parser")

# get the information of a given tag
inm = soup.find(class_="re-DetailHeader-propertyTitle").text
print(inm)
```

You can try and see that with the URL of Fotocasa , works perfectly (gets <Response [200]>) , but with the one from Idealista, doesn't work, (gets <Response [403]>)

the code is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# url = 'https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/vivienda/valencia-capital/aire-acondicionado-trastero-ascensor-no-amueblado/161485852/d'
url = 'https://www.idealista.com/inmueble/97795476/'

headers = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'es,es-ES;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'dnt': '1',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="106", "Microsoft Edge";v="106", "Not;A=Brand";v="99"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/106.0.1370.47'
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(r)

req = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text

# Now that the content is ready, iterate
# through the content using BeautifulSoup:
soup = BeautifulSoup(req, "html.parser")

# get the information of a given tag
inm = soup.find(class_="main-info__title-main").text
print(inm)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your headers are probably fine, but I think you need to include cookies as well.

One way to replicate your browser's request almost exactly is to [go to the network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43R56.png) on the [browser's dev tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools), and then copy the request for the page
[image]
(you *might* need to refresh for it to show up - it's the one with the same **Request URL** as whatever you entered in the address bar)

Then, you can paste the copied cURL somewhere like [curlconverter](https://curlconverter.com/) to convert to python code, and then copy paste *that* into to your code so that you can continue with

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
```

---

**However**, you will have to update the cookies frequently, so it migth be less hassle to use a library or api that can bypass these blocks. For example if you sign up for [ScrapingAnt](https://app.scrapingant.com/signup), and then paste your API token to the code below:

```py
scrapingant_api = 'https://api.scrapingant.com/v2/general'
scrapingant_key = 'YOUR_API_TOKEN' # paste here
url_to_Scrape = 'https://www.idealista.com/inmueble/97795476/'
url = f'{scrapingant_api}?url={url_to_Scrape}&x-api-key={scrapingant_key}'
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
inm = soup.find(class_="main-info__title-main").text
print(inm) # prints "Ático en venta en plaza del Ayuntamiento, 6"
```

---

There is a limit to how many requests you can run on the free tier of ScrapingAnt, though; so I suggest also considering selenium if you'll be needing to scrape an unlimited number of times. If you copy the function from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Driftr95/cbae6710c134df708f44ade8503f6638), you can simply call it like:

```py
# def linkToSoup_selenium .... # paste function into your code

soup = linkToSoup_selenium('https://www.idealista.com/inmueble/97795476/')
inm = soup.find(class_="main-info__title-main").text
print(inm) # prints "Ático en venta en plaza del Ayuntamiento, 6"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should ALWAYS check the robots.txt file if you want to scrape a page. Read this: ( https://dan-suciu.medium.com/the-complete-manual-to-legal-ethical-web-scraping-in-2021-3eeae278b334 )
In the case of your 2nd url it seems like the scraping is not allowed - it is blocked. Try the url  https://www.idealista.com/robots.txt and see the  text, google translates it as:
**Misuse has been detected Access has been blocked
Having trouble accessing the site? Contact support
ID: fc1d890d-6ed6-8959-cd68-de965251f89b
IP: xx.xx.xx.xx
All the best,
The idealist team**

Regards...